# CRM 4.0 - Custom workflow activity that is able to check whether an attribute's value has changed

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, dynamics-crm-4

I was wondering if it is possible to create a custom workflow activity that is able to check whether an attribute's value has actually changed after it was last updated?  If so, could you please provide examples of how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Jennaway has posted some possible solutions on the Microsoft forum:

"create a workflow rule that is triggered only on an update to the attribute that you're interested in, maybe write the attribute name into a custom field, then call a second workflow that does the main work." - although this would not work in my case because the attribute value does not always change when it is updated.

However, he also suggests:

"The alternative approach would be to write a plugin, which can compare the pre and post values of the attribute. One option would be to use the plugin to set an attribute on the entity to indicate if it's a genuine update, and have the workflow read this attribute. Alternatively, the plugin could remove the attribute from the InputParameters if it's value weren't changing, which would stop the workflow from firing." - this is the option that I will be looking at in more detail.

Taken from - http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/1816656f-f34a-4df9-b98f-181a38f053c3/#85c9e290-b059-4e4a-b58f-facc02c73ebe